# Is there an easy way to add spaces to words in a List?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-docx

Alright, so here is what I am trying to do. I want easily convert the text from a text file into a word document. I currently have this...

```
from docx import Document

text_file = "pathToYourTextFile.txt"

#opens document to add text to
document = Document()

#adds the entire contents to a list that we will
#then use to add to the document we just created
fileContents = []
for line in open(text_file):
    row = line.split(' ')
    fileContents += list(row)

#adds all the text we just created to the document as a paragraph
paragraph = document.add_paragraph(fileContents)

#saves the document with all the under the name we give it
document.save('test.docx')
print("Document saved.")
```

Where the text from the text file is read then each word is added to a list. Then all the words are added to the `Document` but the problem is all the words run together and don't have any spaces.

Below is an example of what the text looks like...

```
GetreadytoentertheThrivetimeshowontalk.Radio1170broadcastinglivefromthecenteroftheuniverse.It'SbusinessschoolwithouttheBSfeaturingoptometristturnedentrepreneur.Dr.RobertzoellnerwithusSBA,entrepreneuroftheYearclayClark.Dowehavecominginfromoneofourlistenersthattheyasked?Howcanyoucontrolemployeesthatyoucannotfire?HowcanyoucontrolemployeesthatyoucannotfirewellSteve?Couldyouthrowoutsomeinstanceswherethatcouldbeathingwhereyoucouldn'tfiretosuchasuper?
```

So what I want to know is this the best way to do this? Is there a simpler way? Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you in advance!!!

Comment: There's no easy fix for this because there's no delimiter or easy regex to figure out what word is meant to be in the sentence. By that I mean you won't know where to place the spaces to create the words.

Comment: If I understand correctly, the original text file has spaces and your program is removing them. Which begs the question... why? Why are you splitting on spaces if you want the whole file anyway?

Comment: @SilvioMayolo good point. It was a block of code from another project so it was the best way I could think of getting the words in the list. What would you suggest using instead?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why did you split the line to some words?
If you want to copy everything, you should go with the line(will copy the space and the new-line) instead of splitting it.
So your code will be :

```
from docx import Document

text_file = "pathToYourTextFile.txt"

#opens document to add text to
document = Document()

#adds the entire contents to a list that we will
#then use to add to the document we just created
fileContents = []
for line in open(text_file):
    fileContents += line

#adds all the text we just created to the document as a paragraph
paragraph = document.add_paragraph(fileContents)

#saves the document with all the under the name we give it
document.save('test.docx')
print("Document saved.")
```

Nice commenting btw!

Happy Coding!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `" ".join(fileContents)`, so you need to modify the adding paragraph part to be as the following:

```
fileContents = []
for line in open(text_file):
    row = line.split(' ')
    fileContents += list(row)

#adds all the text we just created to the document as a paragraph
paragraph = document.add_paragraph(" ".join(fileContents))
```

Answer (score 2):

It's not at all clear why you're splitting on spaces.  If you remove `row = line.split(' ')` and make the subsequent line `fileContents += line`, do you get what you want?  You can also restore the newline by following the previous with `fileContents += '\n'`.